# How to deploy a sql database with geo replication using azure resource manager templates

Tags: database, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create an ARM template that will deploy a primary database with an active geo-replicated secondary database, both dbs are for now of the Basic tier. I'm creating the secondary database with "createMode": "OnlineSecondary" and the "sourceDatabaseId" being the primary db already created, however I'm getting the error "This feature is not available for the selected database's edition (Basic)." I thought that as of April 2016, active geo replication is available for all database tiers? Will I be unable to set this up using an ARM template?

The relevant portion of my template is:

```
{
                "name": "[variables('sqlDatabaseName')]",
                "type": "databases",

                "location": "East US",
                "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', ,variables('sqlServerName'), '-east')]"
                ],
                "tags": {
                    "displayName": "SqlDatabase"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "createMode": "OnlineSecondary",
                    "sourceDatabaseId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', concat(variables('sqlServerName'), '-west'), variables('sqlDatabaseName'))]",
                    "collation": "[parameters('deployinfo_sqlDatabaseCollation')]",
                    "edition": "[parameters('deployinfo_sqlDatabaseEdition')]",
                    "maxSizeBytes": "1073741824",
                    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('deployinfo_sqlDatabaseRequestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
                }
            }
```

**Update - added primary db resource json**

This is the resource block for the primary DB:

```
{
                "name": "[variables('sqlDatabaseName')]",
                "type": "databases",
                "location": "West US",
                "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerName'), '-west')]"
                ],
                "tags": {
                    "displayName": "SqlDatabase"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "collation": "[parameters('deployinfo_sqlDatabaseCollation')]",
                    "edition": "[parameters('deployinfo_sqlDatabaseEdition')]",
                    "maxSizeBytes": "1073741824",
                    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('deployinfo_sqlDatabaseRequestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Turns out, if you do not specify the version of sql server you need, it spins up an older version that does not support active geo-replication. I needed to declare the sql servers as version 12.0 to get the replication to work.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Geo-Replication can be configured for Basic tier too and Yes, you will be able to do it using ARM template. I'm currently working on the exact same thing and could do it successfully. My database template for geo-replication looked like this in the first attempt:

```
{
"type": "databases",
"name": "SecondaryDB",
"apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
"location": "West US",
"tags": {
    "displayName": "SqlDatabase"
},
"properties": {
    "createMode": "OnlineSecondary",
    "sourceDatabaseId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', 'primaryserver01', 'PrimaryDB')]",
    "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
    "edition": "Basic",
    "maxSizeBytes": "1073741824",
    "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "Basic"
  },
 "dependsOn": ["[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', 'secondaryserver01')]"]}
```

My best guess is the problem is in the parameters that are passed into the template especially the parameters passed to "edition" and "requestedServiceObjectiveName".

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's good to know someone else has this configured. I am passing "Basic" into both "edition" and "requestedServiceObjectiveName".

Comment: Apart from this almost everything looks the same. Could you also post the template used to create Primary Database. It might help debug the problem.

Comment: I went ahead and added the primary db portion. I had to recreate it as i've since pulled the geo-replication portion out of my template, but its basically what i had before. Both DBs were being passed the same parameters for edition and requestedServiceObjectiveName. Is there a different portion of this process, perhaps in the powershell script, that determines a version of the api?

Comment: No matter what I do I'm not able to replicate this issue on my end. The database is getting created properly with Geo-replication. Have you looked at the possibility of this problem arising from some other section of your template? I would suggest removing everything else from your template and try deploying only the secondary database.

Comment: Thanks for help Flemin, I discovered we actually have some paid MSFT support we can tap to figure this out, I'll update this with the result of that, hopefully shed some light on what I was doing wrong.